# Python: fastest method to fetch a record from a 2D array by search value?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a 2D array (mln rows), not sorted

`[{"ID: "A123", "Data_A": "2.123", "Data_B": "abcd"}, ..., {"ID: "BI451", "Data_A": "2.123", "Data_B": "dcbz"}]`

Need to find a row by "ID" and return it for processing. It is a 1-time action = download the array, find ~100 rows, discard the array.

What is the quickest method? Will converting it to a numpy or pandas.df make it quicker?

Comment: Compared pandas.df to the variant by @user1740577 below.  Pandas.df was 25 times slower in list conversion and 600 times slower in finding the data by ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: *(**this is O(n)**, you can create `dictionary` from `ID` as `key` then find your `dict` with use `ID` as `key` in `dct_id`)*

```
>>> lst_dct = [{"ID": "A123", "Data_A": "2.123", "Data_B": "abcd"},{"ID": "BI451", "Data_A": "2.123", "Data_B": "dcbz"}]

>>> dct_id = {ld['ID'] : ld for ld in lst_dct}

>>> dct_id
{'A123': {'ID': 'A123', 'Data_A': '2.123', 'Data_B': 'abcd'},
 'BI451': {'ID': 'BI451', 'Data_A': '2.123', 'Data_B': 'dcbz'}}

>>> dct_id['A123']
{'ID': 'A123', 'Data_A': '2.123', 'Data_B': 'abcd'}
```

You can use `.get()` and do what you want in `default` if `key` does not exist:

```
>>> dct_id.get('A122', print('Not Found'))
Not Found
```

Comment: thanks. Man, it took me a full day to figure out what it is about :). I'm just a casual programmer struggling to understand the comprehensions, lambdas and other stuff

Comment: @Rockid welcome dude, `dictionary` is very good

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter`, which returns a generator:

```
a = [{"ID": "A123", "Data_A": "2.123", "Data_B": "abcd"}, {"ID": "BI451", "Data_A": "2.123", "Data_B": "dcbz"}]

gen_A123 = filter(lambda d: d['ID'] == 'A123', a)
```

Thus, you can then only take the number of elements that you want (provided you have enough):

```
from itertools import islice
list(islice(gen_A123, 100))

## OR
for item in islice(gen_A123, 100):
    # perform action
```